# Weather Forecasting using neural network

Tags: neural-network, weather, prediction, backpropagation

I am trying to write a program for weather forecasting using Backpropagation. I have the data of different parameters like temperature, humidity, wind speed, sea level pressure etc. I have set 4 parameters (4 nodes) for input layer(temperature, humidity, wind speed, sea level pressure).

Now I am confused about what will be the output/target. Monthly/seasonal division is necessary?
And how can I normalize those 4 different parameters (between -1 to 1 )?

Comment: This is not how it is done typically.  Why use neural net when you have physics?

Comment: @duffymo You're absolutely correct for the standard forecasts.  One could use a clumsy machine learning method to demonstrate *why* domain expertise is important.  However, the field of aggregating an ensemble of forecasts, a statistical area, is somewhat removed from the underlying physics.

Comment: 8 years later and the field is now using NN for parameterization parameter calibration and also the scope to use NN to completely replace parameterizations for clouds, convection and radiative transfer on the sub-grid scale.  That's about the current limit as of 2020

Answer (score 0):

You could treat this as a multi-class classification problem. Let us say you want to predict if the weather will be sunny, rainy, cloudy, windy. These would be your classes to classify.

You could normalize the input features by the formula : (x-xbar)/mu, where xbar is average of the feature and mu the stdev of the feature.

Comment: The standard deviation is usually called sigma und the real mean is often written as mu.